# How to keep redis server running

Tags: redis

I am using redis for session support in nodejs app. I have installed redis server and it works when I run redis-server, but when I close terminal redis stops and does not work. How do I keep redis server running after closing the terminal?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The easiest way to launch Redis as a daemon is to edit the configuration file and change the following line:

```
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' if you need it.
# Note that Redis will write a pid file in /var/run/redis.pid when daemonized.
daemonize yes
```

Be sure to provide the configuration file on the redis-server command line when you launch it.

An example of configuration file is provided in the Redis distribution.

Comment: I saw this is how you run it as a daemon, but then what command do you use to run it as a daemon?

Comment: It depends on the platform and OS distribution.

Comment: next search result down https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis

Comment: There are a few problems with this answer: 1) it doesn't tell the user where the configuration file is stored. 2) It doesn't say which platform this answer applies to (if there are different locations for the configuration file; at least provide which platform you installed it under to get this result) 3) it doesn't even say what the name of the configuration file is.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea, which solved my issue. I had the `daemonize` option set to yes and was trying to keep its Docker container alive with the `-D FOREGROUND` but it was not working and the container was exiting. I got rid of this option and changed the `daemonize` option back to no, and it worked, the container is kept alive.

Comment: `daemonize yes` is not available on Windows. See this superuser answer for how to run redis-server on the background without using a service on Windows: https://superuser.com/a/198530/136896. As for Windows versions of redis, there are many flavors, but https://github.com/tporadowski/redis seems the most up-to-date, easily available binary as of Feb 2020

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I know this is old, but to be fair, you can't know which platform the user is running or if he is running a custom setup, so I wouldn't call this a "problem", his answer is correct in *any* platform, that's the point. OP didn't specify OS.

Comment: sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf using this command you can find the config file on ubuntu

Answer (score 234):

And, if you'd like a quick option, run: `redis-server --daemonize yes`.

Comment: may I ask what's the difference between this and `redis-server &`?

Comment: @Uduse If you ran it with `&` at the end, then when you exited the terminal the server process would be killed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595391/6263317

Comment: @JonDeaton thanks for the explanation, but then what about using `nohup redis-server &` vs `redis-server --daemonize`? I mean, it seems that there's some way to achieve the same functionality without using `--daemonize` and that option is not really needed.

Answer (score 44):

As mentioned by @DidierSpezia in his answer,

Set `daemonize yes` in Redis conf file.
Set `daemonize yes` in Redis conf file at `/path/to/redis.conf` Generally 
it should be there at `/etc/`.

And :

Then trigger redis-server with the conf file as an argument:

```
./redis-server /etc/redis.conf
```

**UPDATE** 
You may directly run the redis with `demonize` flag as well

```
redis-server --daemonize yes
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is *mostly outdated*.
While the question *is old*, Google still ranks this highly, so allow me to correct this.

The OP did not provide any detail about his setup, but you can assume it is a linux, and he doesn't mention containers, so you can also assume he is running redis without them.

There is three detail that make **the accepted answer a thing to forget**

- Most (popular) distros come with systemd by default
- Most (popular) distros have redis in their official repos
- that official redis package installs systemd service for redis

So

- It will have `supervised systemd` in its default config
- To start: the redis daemon with `sudo systemctl start redis@instanceName` where you substitue "instanceName". Also `sudo systemctl enable redis@instanceName` for auto-starting on boot. (BTW, forget about `service start`, and init scripts already! These are less portable nowdays than calling directly `systemctl`).
- do *NOT* set to `daemonize: yes`, that will interfere with the systemd supervisioning redis!

Systemd will supervise, restart your redis, and you can set service depenedencies and service preconditions to/for it, even for a custom executable it is not that hard, search for systemd unit files (you'll need a ~10 lines config file). Chances are, you'd want it.

If the three detail (making systemd the correct answer) are not met/relevant, you are most likely running redis containerized. For docker/podman/etc., it is another question altogether... (no systemd in the inner linux, but you'd have to (or already do) supervise(d) the container-daemon itself)

Comment: This is the way to have an always running service, Redis service, in this case. Think of a scenario where your server gets restarted... I would re-choose this answer as accepted, if I could!