# How can I run redis on the editor?

Tags: redis, editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use editor sublime text 3

I usually run redis like this :
[image]

I click redis-server. Then I click again redis-client

Seems like that, it's less efficient. Can I do that with an editor? Example sublime text 3 editor

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do that by using editor. 
In editors, you'll get option to open console window(or Terminal). But I think that will not help you because that will be same as you are using it currently(i.e by command prompt as shown in images shared by you).

Rest if you want to keep *Redis* to keep running, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14821527/5059727). On other hand if you want some **GUI for Redis**, then you can try [Redis Desktop Manager](https://redisdesktop.com/). That will better help you out for your manipulations.