# How can I install Redis in shared hosting

Tags: laravel, redis, cpanel, shared-hosting

I'm working on a Laravel project and I'm using Redis for caching and stuff like that, everything is fine when I'm developing it but what should I do when I deploy the project, what are the requirements to run Redis on a host.
And do the shared hosting provide me the access to Redis? I think not, I read a lot about no supporting for Redis in shared hosting, so what should I do, is there an alternative way to run Redis? or is there a shared hosting supports it, please mention it.
Any recommendations, please :(

I got one of my questions here which is, how to keep the server running forever without running it from the Terminal.
[How to keep redis server running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816892/how-to-keep-redis-server-running)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the provider if they support Redis.

Redis is a software that needs to be installed on the web server or any server your web server has access to. It is not possible to install this yourself on a shared hosting.

Comment: What if I have access to the Terminal can I do that myself?

Comment: If you have root access, yes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install redis by yourself. You need to ask to your hosting company if they provide redis. You might need to pay extra for that. But, It would be a rare instance if hosting company provides redis by default on shared hosting. If you want good hosting service, I would recomment digitalocean.com. They provide servers at affordable rates

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible they provide me a Cpanel + Redis?

Comment: No I don't think your hosting service will provide redis specially for you. Either you can go for dedicated server or you can search hosting service which provides you redis by default for share hosting