# Running Redis server in the background (while not running terminal)?

Tags: redis

**Problem:**

I can't seem to figure out how to keep Redis server running when I exit terminal.

**Server:**

I installed Redis using this quickstart guide: https://redis.io/topics/quickstart

We are running it on an OVH VPS:

```
Architecture:   x86_64
Operating System:   linux
```

**What have I tried:**

```
redis-server --daemonize yes
```

Tried the above but would only work when terminal remains open. As soon as I close the terminal the redis server stops.

```
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' if you need it.
# Note that Redis will write a pid file in /var/run/redis.pid when daemonized.
daemonize yes
```

I changed the configuration but still, whenever I close the terminal the Redis server stops.

```
nohup redis-server &
```

Tried with nohup but that aswell didn't work as soon as I closed the terminal.

> [How to keep redis server running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816892/how-to-keep-redis-server-running)

Comment: How did you test it stopped when you closed the terminal? When you add the `--daemonize yes` option, does it create the `pid` file you mention? Be  sure to delete it before testing.

Comment: If we don't find a solution, you can certainly make it work with `tmux` or GNU `screen`, but ideally we'll find a solution without those.

Comment: By the way, folks normally start Redis using `systemd` or SysV Init.

Comment: @MarkSetchell 
Well, other features depend on Redis. As soon as I close the terminal those features can't connect to Redis. If I open terminal and type something like {redis-cli} it will return: 
{Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused}. 

It does not seem to create the redis.pid.

Comment: Mmm, the lack of a PID file implies something is wrong. Maybe the config file you are editing is not the one Redis is using? Try `redis-cli info | grep -i config_file` to be sure.

Comment: https://uploadedcontent.com/2020-04-03-19-57-19-ZTldj.png - Returned this.

Comment: Ok, so it's not using the config file you are editing! Try starting it with `nohup redis-server /path/to/configfile/with/daemonize/yes &`

Comment: I think something is going wrong.
https://uploadedcontent.com/2020-04-03-20-31-24-U03BH.png