# Redis server connection after reboot

Tags: redis

I have redis installed on Debian 11 (5.10.205-2), I have followed this page [How to keep redis server running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816892/how-to-keep-redis-server-running) to no avail.

`sudo systemctl enable redis-server.service`

gives the output

`Synchronizing state of redis-server.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install. Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable redis-server`

The output of

`systemctl status redis-server.service`

`Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-01-25 07:38:00 GMT; 11min ago`

Now if I run

`redis-cli ping`

I get

`Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`

So I run

`redis-server --daemonize yes`

and the output of `redis-cli ping` is PONG

After a reboot the output of `redis-cli ping` is `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`

Any ideas?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I added

`@reboot redis-server --daemonize yes`

to crontab -e and it seems to haved worked, no idea if this is avisable but hey, it works.